# Python requests and form button interaction issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I get one free ebook a day from Packt Publishing with their "Free Learning - Free Technology Ebooks" promo. I'm trying to automate this process. I do a POST against their root path to login, after that I do a GET on the promo URL and use BeautifulSoup 4 to get the HREF of the "claim your free ebook" link, and now I'm stuck. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

USERNAME = 'email@email.com'
PASSWORD = 'secret'
BASE_URL = 'https://www.packtpub.com'
PROMO_URL = 'https://www.packtpub.com/packt/offers/free-learning'

session = requests.session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
session.post(BASE_URL, {"username": USERNAME, "password": PASSWORD}, headers=headers)

response = session.get(PROMO_URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
current_offer_href = BASE_URL + soup.find("div", {"class": "free-ebook"}).a['href']
print(current_offer_href)
print(session.post(current_offer_href, headers=headers))
```

The `current_offer_href` is holding the correct value, if you go to the site today (8/NOV/2016) and inspect the button you will find it:

[image]

In this case, my `current_offer_href` is holding `https://www.packtpub.com/freelearning-claim/21558/21478`.

If I try to do a POST against `current_offer_href` like in my code I receive `<Response [404]>`. In reality what I should be getting is a redirect to `https://www.packtpub.com/account/my-ebooks`, because that's what happen if I click the button manually on the site. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are filtered server side based on your user agent. To solve the issue change user agent.

Comment: I tried using `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2810.1 Safari/537.36` (Jul 31, 2016) from http://ua.theafh.net, but I got the same `<Response [404]>`. Any other idea?